# Getting the error "The procedure entry point _ZdaPvj could not be located in the dynamic link library C:\Qt\4.8.6\bin\qmake.exe" when installing Qt

Tags: c++, windows, qt, gcc

I'm using Windows, and whenever I run the following

```
configure -release -opensource -confirm-license -static -no-sql-sqlite -no-qt3support -no-opengl -qt-zlib -no-gif -qt-libpng -qt-libmng -no-libtiff -qt-libjpeg -no-dsp -no-vcproj -no-openssl -no-dbus -no-phonon -no-phonon-backend -no-multimedia -no-audio-backend -no-webkit -no-script -no-scripttools -no-declarative -no-declarative-debug -qt-style-windows -qt-style-windowsxp -qt-style-windowsvista -no-style-plastique -no-style-cleanlooks -no-style-motif -no-style-cde -nomake demos -nomake examples
```

right after it attempts to run qmake, I get this error.

> The procedure entry point _ZdaPvj could not be located in the dynamic
>   link library C:\Qt\4.8.6\bin\qmake.exe” when installing Qt

I've checked everywhere and I cannot figure out what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try windows7,I installed Qt4.8.6 on windows10 and found that there are many problems.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen when you compile against a Qt version A, but the program is loading libraries at startup from Qt version B, where B is older than A.
Solution: Analyse which libraries are loaded when starting the program. They should be of the same version or newer than the libraries you have linked when building the program.